# Regular Expression Lookarounds

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

Trying to match a word unless it's contained within asterisks. Here's what I've got:

`(?<!\*)\b(word)\b(?!\*)`

The problem is that it won't match **`*word`** or **`word*`** as it should, since I want it to match every permutation except for **`*word*`**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution, should match any word, not just "word":

```
(?<!\*)\b\w+\b|\b\w+\b(?!\*)
```

The key here is to look for two situations where an asterisk may occur, i.e. at the start **OR** at the end of a word.

Answer (score 2):

Then you need an alternation.

```
(?<!\*)\bword\b|\bword\b(?!\*)
```

See [it on Regexr](http://regexr.com?358tb).

Your problem is, that the whole regex fails, as soon as one assertion is true. My way you allow the `*` on one side, but it fails, when `*` is on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Some divertissement:
`(?(?<=\*)word(?!\*)|word(?=\*))`

**Explanation:**

```
(?                      # if
    (?<=\*)             # there is * before 
        word(?!\*)      # then match word not followed by *
        |               # else
        word(?=\*)      # match word followed by *
)                       # end if
```

[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/uA9bB2)